# How to set a preallocated message as field using reflection in protobuf on C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a code like this:

```
TestMessage* output;
::google::protobuf::Message* input;
// ...
auto extension_field = input->GetDescriptor()->extension(i);
// ...
auto reflection = output->GetReflection();
reflection->MutableMessage(output, extension_field)->CopyFrom(*input);
```

This code takes two messages, checks that the one is an extension of the other, copies input message to the corresponding extension field of output message.

I want to optimise it - and replace copying with "moving". How can I do it using `reflection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use `Reflection::Swap` in place of `CopyFrom`.  The top-level object won't be consumed, but all of its child objects (strings, submessages, etc.) will be.

```
auto msg = reflection->MutableMessage(output, output_field);
msg->GetReflection()->Swap(msg, input);
delete input;
```

Comment: Your suggestion about `output_field` is correct. You can remove the second part of your answer - I will update question.

Comment: OK, removed that part.

Comment: Also, there is minor inconsistency in your answer - I can't do `reflection->Swap(reflection->MutableMessage(...), input)` since the first argument to Swap() is not the same message, that provides `reflection`. Protobuf complains about it on runtime, so it should be another reflection.